# Question about the proof of convergence of power series for complex numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I am looking at the proof for convergence of a power series if $|z|< R$, in the proof we defined $l = \limsup_{n\to\infty} (|a_n|)^{1/n}$, the lecturer then states that, $$l = \limsup_{n\to\infty} (|a_n|)^{1/n} = \lim_{N\to \infty} \left(\sup _{n\geq N} (|a_n|)^{1/n}\right)$$ and denotes $C_N = \sup _{n\geq N} (|a_n|)^{1/n}$ and states that since $C_N$ is decreasing then limit of $C_N$ as $N\to \infty$ is $l$, so there exists a $N$ s.t. $C_N < l + \epsilon$ for a positive epsilon.

I have two questions:

1) How did he equate $= \limsup_{n\to\infty} (|a_n|)^{1/n} = \lim_{N\to \infty} \left(\sup _{n\geq N} (|a_n|)^{1/n}\right)$

2) Why does $C_N$ being decreasing do anything? Surely by the definition of $C_N$ and the equation above we have that $\lim_N C_N = l$ and by the definition of a limit we get $C_N < l + \epsilon$?

Any help please

Answer (score 1):

1. It is the definition of $\limsup$.
2. $(C_n)$ is a decreasing sequence, bounded below (by $0$). The monotone convergence theorem ensures $(C_N)$ has a limit as $N$ tends to infinity.

Comment: HOw is it bounded below by 0

Comment: It's an absolute value.